# Dynamically Add/Remove rows with JQuery, bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4

Hello I`m writing project, tests(english physics, etc.), using jstl,bootstrap and jquery.
I need form to create Test with questions and answers. I stuck on one moment. 
I dynamically creating questions and answers, but when I trying to delete question. it not delete answers which was added.
and also how to pack everything in one bean to send it to server for example --> test(int time ,string name, list(question(string name, boolean isMultAnswers ,list(answer(string answer, boolean validity)))

```js
jQuery('.plus').click(function(){

   jQuery('.information_json_plus_answer').before(
            '<tr>' +
            '<td><input type="text" class="col-xs-5" id="information_json_name[]" placeholder="answer"></td>' +
            '<td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="information_json_val[]"></td>' +
            '<td><span class="btn btn-danger minus pull-right">&ndash;</span></td>' +
            '</tr>');
});


jQuery('.plus-new').click(function(){
 jQuery('.information_json_new').before(
        '<tr>' +
  '<th>question</th>' +
  '<th>multanswer</th>' +
  '<th></th>' +
 '</tr>'+
 '<tr>' +
  '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="information_json_name[]" placeholder="Question"></td>' +
  '<td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="information_json_val[]"></td>' +
  '<td><span class="btn btn-danger minus pull-right">&ndash;</span></td>' +
    '</tr>'+
    '<tr class="information_json_plus">'+
        '<td></td>'+
        '<td></td>'+
        '<td><span class="btn btn-success plus pull-right">+</span></td>'+
    '</tr>'
    );
    
});

jQuery(document).on('click', '.minus', function(){
 jQuery( this ).closest( 'tr' ).remove(); 
    jQuery(this).closest('plus').remove();
   
});
jQuery(document).on('click', '.plus', function(){
 jQuery( this ).closest( 'tr' ).before(
        '<tr>' +
            '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="information_json_name[]" placeholder="answer"></td>' +
            '<td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="information_json_val[]" placeholder="chbox"></td>' +
            '<td><span class="btn btn-danger minus pull-right">&ndash;</span></td>' +
        '</tr>'
        );
});
```

```css
.information_json, .information_json * {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
.table {
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 100%;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 background-color: transparent;
 border-spacing: 0;
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
.pull-right {float: left;}
.form-control {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 34px;
 padding: 6px 12px;
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 1.42857143;
 color: #555;
 background-color: #fff;
 background-image: none;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius: 4px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
 box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
 -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,-webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
 -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
 transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
}
.btn {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 6px 12px;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: 400;
 line-height: 1.42857143;
 text-align: center;
 white-space: nowrap;
 vertical-align: middle;
 -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
 touch-action: manipulation;
 cursor: pointer;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
 background-image: none;
 border: 1px solid transparent;
 border-radius: 4px;
}
.btn-danger {
 color: #fff;
 background-color: #d9534f;
 border-color: #d43f3a;
}
.btn-success {
 color: #fff;
 background-color: #5cb85c;
 border-color: #4cae4c;
}
.plus-new {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table information_json">

    <tr class="information_json_new">
  <td></td>
  <td colspan="2"><span class="btn btn-success plus-new pull-right">+</span></td>
    </tr>
    
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have two tr's which are stacked and you are only telling it to remove one (closest). An easy fix would be to move the question and multi-answer html into the tr with the textbox and buttons or a quick and dirty fix would be to:

Try changing:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.minus', function(){
    jQuery( this ).closest( 'tr' ).remove(); 
    jQuery(this).closest('plus').remove();
});
```

To this:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.minus', function(){
            $(this).closest( 'tr' ).remove();
            $(this).closest( 'tr.question' ).remove(); 
            $(this).closest('plus').remove();
});
```

and add:

```
class="question"
```

To this tr:

```
jQuery('.information_json_new').before(
     '<tr>'
```

Hopefully this works out for you.

Comment: Thanks a bit helped, but add button is still not removing. and i can add answers with no question.